# Can vCard 4.0 store more than 1 vCard contact that are not part of the group?

Tags: formatting, format, vcf-vcard, carddav

In vCard 4.0 RFC 6350 I see the following example in [MEMBER property description](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6350#section-6.6.5), which is an example of vCard group:

```
 BEGIN:VCARD
 VERSION:4.0
 KIND:group
 FN:The Doe family
 MEMBER:urn:uuid:03a0e51f-d1aa-4385-8a53-e29025acd8af
 MEMBER:urn:uuid:b8767877-b4a1-4c70-9acc-505d3819e519
 END:VCARD
 BEGIN:VCARD
 VERSION:4.0
 FN:John Doe
 UID:urn:uuid:03a0e51f-d1aa-4385-8a53-e29025acd8af
 END:VCARD
 BEGIN:VCARD
 VERSION:4.0
 FN:Jane Doe
 UID:urn:uuid:b8767877-b4a1-4c70-9acc-505d3819e519
 END:VCARD
```

As far as I understand both contacts as well as group in the above example are stored and served as a single vCard file (or single CardDAV request/respose).

Can a vCard file or CardDAV request/respose contain more than one vCard contact, that are not part of the group. For example like this:

```
 BEGIN:VCARD
 VERSION:4.0
 FN:John Doe
 END:VCARD
 BEGIN:VCARD
 VERSION:4.0
 FN:Jane Doe
 END:VCARD
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A vCard 4 entity can contain a set of vCards, check [RFC 6350 ABNF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6350#section-3.3):

> vcard-entity = 1*vcard

One or more, type doesn't matter.

But you are also asking about [CardDAV](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6352). In CardDAV each vCard is always in a separate HTTP resource / a resource is never supposed to contain a stream of vCards. Check [RFC 6352 Address Object Resources](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6352#section-5.1):

> Address object resources contained in address book collections *MUST
> contain a single vCard component only*.

This includes groups (a vCard group in CardDAV is an own resource and doesn't contain the members).

If you want to retrieve multiple CardDAV resources in a single step, use a [multiget](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6352#section-8.7) or [addressbook-query](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6352#section-8.6) REPORT.

Comment: you are right and now I see this is true not only for v4.0 but for v3.0 and v2.1. In v2.1 I found: "A vCard is a data stream consisting of one or more vCard objects."